# How to make application scale to large (tablet) screen in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, android-layout

I'm just getting into developing on Android and want to try my hand at developing a Tablet app. The problem is, no matter what I've tried so far, deploying the app results in a scaled down version of the app, running at the top of the screen. It appears about the size of a mobile app, and the rest of the screen is just blank.

How can I make my the application recognize that it's on a tablet and scale the screen up?

I've tried changing the screen size in the layout XML WYSIWYG editor, but am to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make two changes to get it to work:

- Compile against 3.0 (API 11)
- Add `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>` to my manifest.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put following in your application manifest (AndroidManifest.xml):

`<supports screens ... android:xlargeScreens="true">`

see: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html ("Extra Large Screens" section)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, and you may have found the answer already. Nevertheless, I made a tool to that can scale your layouts to tablets and small screen devices alike:

http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html