# Scale phone app layout to tablet sized screens in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, scale, tablet

I made an Android app. i want it to be usable on tablets as well, with the same layout files. however, instead of 'scaling' up the interface to match the size of the tablet, im getting it in the size of the phone interface, just on a big display, resulting in a-lot of mess.

i tried doing things like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132912/how-to-make-application-scale-to-large-tablet-screen-in-android-sdk), but i cant because of many reasons (for example, im using libraries that did not exist back then).

How can i accomplish my task, besides doing different layout files for all sizes? please dont link me [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), i read that a few times and could not understand how to make it work properly (besides some limitLarge property that made it scale in an ugly and blurry way).

thanks!

Edit: Example layout and the code following:

This is how it looks on a phone:

[image]

And this is how it looks on a tablet:

[image]

you can see the layout 'kept' its formation, but i want it to 'scale up' to take up the entire screen. i 'feel' the problem lies within the 'dp' size unit (since the big screen has more 'dp'?), but i cant fix it. I'm relatively new on this type of development, so please help me out :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/authLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="FTW Name Placeholder"
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textViewInst"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Connect"
            android:id="@+id/btnConnect"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Username:"
                android:id="@+id/textView58" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Password"
                android:id="@+id/textView59" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Auth"
            android:id="@+id/authBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: without any layout files we cannot even begin to help you. if you have hard  height/width values you should remove them and use `match_parent/wrap_content` on your layouts

Comment: Can you post a layout example?

Comment: @EdGeorge I was not asking for "free code", was asking for the correct setting or methodology to do so.
I will post a layout example in a few moments

Comment: my apologies, I misread the question

Answer (score 1):

For that can you set width and height in dimens.xml in res/values-sw600dp this for 7" tablet

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to target any specific api to develop a tablet app, just provide resources targeted for higher densities

You can store layouts with the same name but different density suffixes, for example

layout/mylayout.xml - any device
layout-w700dp/mylayout.xml - devices with a width of at least 700dp.

Tablets start at around 700dp (This value was obtained from my experience, no actual data so don't quote me on it)

Read these documents to learn more

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

PS
Do yourself a favor and target 4.0 and up at the very 
least, older devices are a pain to work with and they have very little market share now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I do develop for Android 4+.

I will post a sample layout and explain my question further.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely ever want to set hard widths like this

```
android:layout_width="220dp"
```

Everywhere you have something like that you need to replace it with `match_parent` that will ensure that the width is the same size as your parent layout width

same with your buttons where you have this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

make them match parent and they will span the width of the screen.

There is no need to store `dimens` in separate folders

Comment: but lets say i dont want to take the full width of the parent, and content is empty at the beginning. should i use 'weights'? would that work?
what about font sizes?

Comment: you already pretty much take the full width of your parent in your phone layout, plus just because it looks like that on that device does not mean thats how it looks on others with bigger or smaller screens. Smaller screens your layout might be cut off on the sides. What about font sizes?